# I am getting multiple errors while setting up pom.xml for Selenium We driver automation using Maven framework

Tags: selenium, maven, selenium-webdriver

Even though I have taken the necessary selenium Web driver dependency from below link -**https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java**
Its giving error on pom.xml file. Due to this I am unable to download the necessary reference libraries of selenium web driver. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJbbd.jpg)
I have attached the errors which are shown in eclipse IDE.
Anyone please give me an accurate solution for this.

Comment: What do you mean by: `I have taken the necessary selenium Web driver dependency from ..` exactly?

Comment: Have you rebuilt your project? and have you did `mvn -install`?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.